# Modifying queue of class in systemverilog function

Tags: system-verilog

I met a problem when I trying to modify a queue of class in systemverilog function.

Here are the codes:

```
module my_module;

class dscr;
   logic mode;

   function void print_dscr;
        $display("mode = %d", this.mode);
   endfunction
endclass

dscr a_dscr_q[$];
dscr b_dscr_q[$];

initial begin 
    descriptor_decode(0, a_dscr_q);
    for (int I=0; I<a_dscr_q.size(); i++)
       a_dscr_q[i].print_dscr();

    descriptor_decode(1, b_dscr_q);
    for (int I=0; I<a_dscr_q.size(); i++)
       a_dscr_q[i].print_dscr();
    for (int I=0; I<b_dscr_q.size(); i++)
       b_dscr_q[i].print_dscr();
end


function void descriptor_decode(logic mode, ref dscr dscr_q[$]);
    dscr dscr_dec = new;
    dscr_dec.mode = mode;

    dscr_q.pushback(dscr_dec);
endfunction

endmodule
```

I am trying to create different class queue in function "descriptor_decoder", with different value of input mode. In function, I firstly create a new dscr class and then push it to a class queue. However the simulation result are:

```
mode = 0
mode = 1
mode = 1
```

The first time I call the function, it did push back the correct class into a_dscr_q. But the second function call, it seems the class is push back into both a_dscr_q and b_dscr_q. I am quite confused, What happened in here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code was made illegal syntax in the IEEE 1800-2009 LRM because of the very problem you are experiencing. Most tools now report this as an error.

Your `descriptor_decode` is function with a static lifetime, and the `dscr_dec` variable declared inside it has a static lifetime as well.

You are not allowed to have an initialization on a variable whose lifetime is implicitly static and has the option to be declared automatic. This is because unlike most programming languages, the default lifetime of variables in a SystemVerilog function is static, and initialization of static variables happens once before time 0, not each occurrence of calling the function. In your example, you are expecting `dscr_dec` to behave as an automatic. 
So you need to make one of the following code changes:

- explicitly declare `dscr_dec` automatic
- declare the function automatic, which makes variables declared inside it implicitly automatic
- declare the module automatic, which makes functions declared inside it implicitly automatic
- split the declaration and initialization do that the initialization happens when the function gets called.